# How do I fix homebrew error message about "No available formula"

Tags: homebrew

When I run `brew doctor`, I get the following results:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "coin-or-tools/coinor/clp" 
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap coin-or-tools/coinor
```

I've never deliberately installed `clp`, although this message started showing up after I installed `why3`, which I later deleted (because I intend to use [the approach suggested by Laboratoire de Recherche en Informatique](https://www.lri.fr/~marche/MPRI-2-36-1/install.html#mac) instead).

As an experiment, I decided to just go ahead and tap that keg, but I then got the following results:

```
▶ brew doctor
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps: 
 * coin-or-tools/coinor/coin_data_sample
 * dreal/coinor/coin_data_sample
```

I then tried untapping `dreal/coinor` and installing `clp`, but this failed because `Required package CoinUtils not available`. At this point, I felt like I was probably going too deep down this rabbit hole and pulled up, specifically, I untapped `coin-or-tools/coinor` and retapped `dreal/coinor`. Naturally, the original problem persists.

What is the best approach for fixing this problem, or should I just fight my OCD tendencies and just ignore it?

Comment: From where and how did you install why3 the first time?

Comment: ...and what is your macOS/OS X version?

Comment: I first installed why3 via homebrew, but then later via opam per the approach suggested by Laboratoire de Recherche en Informatique.
My macOS is Sierra, 10.12.3 (16D32)

Comment: `brew install why3` gives me `No formulae found in taps`. From which tap did you install it?

Comment: I used the `mht208/formal` tap (`mht208/formal/why3`).

Comment: [That formula](https://github.com/mht208/homebrew-formal/blob/18cd58a6785aa3f06e8590fe69f033924b012ecb/why3.rb) doesn’t seem to depend on `clp`.

Comment: Does `ls $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/clp` give something?

Comment: @bfontaine: 
`▶ ls $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/clp` yields
`ls: /usr/local/Cellar/clp: No such file or directory`

Comment: I had a theory but I can’t confirm it. Do you still have the issue?

Comment: @bfontaine: I do, along with a couple new ones. :) (unlinked kegs and outdated XQuartz)

Answer (score -2):

If you have been using homebrew for longer and never removed older versions (using, for example `brew cleanup`), chances are that some older version of your program may still be around. If you want to simply activate that previous version, `brew switch` is the easiest way to do this.

you have to Check, whether the version is available as a tap.

thanks @python

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Comment: Since Homebrew 1.9, released in January of this year, old versions are removed when you upgrade a formula.